# Whats's the code that gives the meaning of your date cannot be more than the current date?

Tags: php, sql, date

Whats's the code that gives the meaning of your date cannot be more than the current date?

```
<?php
else if($cust_dob  date("d-m-y")){
echo "Error : Your date of birth cannot be in future.";
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$cust_dob`? `'20-04-1986'`? `'1990-01-13'`? A timestamp? A `DateTime` object?

Comment: How do they insert their birthday? Why dont use dropdown menu and just give a limit of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes:

```
$cust_dob = "2013-09-03";

if(strtotime($cust_dob) > time())
    echo "Error : Your date of birth cannot be in future.";
```

Comment: Why use `strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))` if you can just use `time()`?

Comment: Definitely you right! It's more quick. I used `strtotime` because of `strtotime($cust_dob)` using before. I missing `time()`. Thanks